# Rails: track users group by hour created_at and ip address

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, group-by

I have the following `impression` model that tracks all users interactions within the app:

```
class Impression
  belongs_to :user
end

create_table :impressions do
  t.string :ip_address
  t.integer :user_id
  t.datetime :created_at
end
```

I need to show a count of all impressions grouped by `ip_address` and `created_at` (per hour)

Let's say a user hits `10 times` a certain page today at a random time, we have then `10 impressions` stored. Each one of theses impressions has the ip_address and timestamps.

The result of the query should be like:

```
created_at          user_id         ip_address   count
10/08/2014 6pm            1          127.0.0.1       2
10/08/2014 4pm            1          127.0.0.1       4
10/08/2014 1pm            1          127.0.0.1       2
10/08/2014 1pm            1          82.125.121.101  1
10/08/2014 10am           1          127.0.0.1       1
```

In this example the sum of impressions is 10 which is correct.

At the hour around `1pm` the user visits the app 3 times, twice in localhost and once with ip_address 82.125.121.101.

Here is my query so far:

```
Impression.where(user_id: 1).group_by_hour(:created_at).group(:ip_address).size.order('created_at desc')
```

But the result is neither ordered `created_at desc` nor correct in counts.

I use the following groupdate gem `https://github.com/ankane/groupdate` that groups by hour.

Comment: how is `group_by_hour(:created_at)` defined?

Comment: I'm using groupdate gem that handle grouping by hour/day/month...
https://github.com/ankane/groupdate

Comment: Looking at the sql generated, the alias given by gem is `hour` so use that to order the results `Impression.where(user_id: 1).group_by_hour(:created_at).group(:ip_address).order('hour ASC').count(:id)`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using postgresql you could use `date_trunc`:

```
  SELECT date_trunc('hour', created_at) AS h, ip_address, COUNT(*)
    FROM users
GROUP BY h, ip_address
```

And not related to your actual question, but postgresql has an IP address datatype built in which you could use instead of a string. I think the main reason to use it is just to enforce that it's a valid IP address when you're inserting records.